# Why does the outside of my glass of coffee look strange?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, glass

I'm currently following Blender Guru's beginner donut tutorial and I just completed Level 3 Part 4 where we made coffee, but for some reason, the liquid as viewed from the outside of the glass looks strange. Here’s the picture of the render: [image: Coffee] Maybe this is what it is supposed to look like, but please tell me how to fix this if this is wrong. Thank you!

By the way, I am using the Blender 2.8 default denoiser with 128 samples and the Filmic Blender configuration that Blender Guru recommended.

Comment: Do you mean the muddy pattern? That is caused by the denoiser not being able to properly eliminate the noise.

Comment: I would suggest a good  step would be to render the coffee without the glass, to see if the root problem is about the interaction between the refractive surfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Did you do the part where you slightly scaled up the liquid so it overlapped the glass a little bit?  That's what it looks like to me.

Comment: Yes, I did that, but I still have the problem :(